# How to add record into an javascript array by using code below?

Tags: javascript

How to show records on index page when we add records using HTML form on another page into an array

Comment: Your code works. Simplified: `questions.push(new Question(question, [option1, option2, option3, option4], answer));`
  just `console.log(questions)` after the alert to see

Comment: This: _My code below is not working properly._ - You didn't describe what _not working properly_ means. Please do that.

Comment: @RandyCasburn No it should NOT be -1 - he wants to ADD a question, not change the LAST question. His code works just fine as is

Comment: @mplungjan error is when I want to display array result into index page.I am unable to see the array record that I have entered uisng HTML form.

Comment: that would be because you don't have any code that attempts to do that.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I have code.The array record is display on the index page expect those records that I have entered using HTML FORM

Comment: You have no code that does anything with the content of the `questions` array other than alerting its length property and logging the array to the console. Please point out what code you have that you believe places the array contents into the HTML.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I am going to edit. Please have a look.

Comment: You likely also want a server process that SAVES the entered questions permanently no?

Comment: @mplungjan not permanently by save just temporary..

Comment: You still need a display function

Comment: @mplungjan please help.

Comment: We still do not know what you need.

Comment: You deleted all relevant code

Comment: Where is function Quiz and how are you planning to SAVE the questions to show to someone else in the index.html?

Comment: @mplungjan please check it now. I have edit again.

Comment: @RandyCasburn    Please have a look.If u can help me.Thanks

Comment: Please click the `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] and update your description with expected and actual results - I still have no idea of your actual problem other than not figuring out yet how to format your code into a question we can answer

Comment: @mplungjan Please check. I have shared codepen link. https://codepen.io/yasir38/project/editor/AQGoGN#0

Comment: @mplungjan basically, When I add a question using html form from createQuestion.html page and I want to display this question into index.hmtl page.Please help.Thanks

Comment: But you add the questions and you want to show it to someone else on their computer, then you need to STORE the questions on the SERVER

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use sessionStorage.setItem() and sessionStorage.getItem() to store question into questions's array.